# Symfony2: PrePersist/PreUpdate lifecycle-event not fired

Tags: events, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

Two Entities **GalleryAlbum** and **GalleryImage** have OneToMany/ManyToOne relationship:

`One GalleryAlbum ==== can have ====> Many GalleryImage`

`Many GalleryImage === can be in ===> One GalleryAlbum`

(sources below)

**What is the problem?**

1. Adding (uploading) files to GalleryAlbum
2. $em->persist($album)
3. $em->flush()
4. For each uploaded file GalleryAlbum class creates and adds to $images a new GalleryImage entity
5. My ECHO/EXIT test is not shown (GalleryImage's prePersist/preUpdate event callback function named preUpload is not triggered!)
6. My new images are not saved to the database? Why?

**What is weird!** *If I do:*

1. Adding (uploading) files
2. $em->persist($album)
3. $em->flush()
4. **again $em->flush()**
5. My ECHO/EXIT test is shown (GalleryImage's prePersist/preUpdate event callback function named preUpload is triggered!)
6. (if i delete echo/exit) My new GalleryImages are saved now!!!

**Why?**

Why is preUpload never triggered when I flush() once, and is triggered when I flush() twice?

*# src GalleryAlbum.php*

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
     * @ORM\Table(name="gallery_album")
     */
    class GalleryAlbum
    {
        // some properties like id, name, description, etc

        /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="GalleryImage", mappedBy="parent")
         */
        protected $images;

        /* Files container. Used for upload service. Must not be persisted. */

        protected $files;    

        /* @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=TRUE)
         *
         * if set to true will updateing object and calling preUpdate event callback
         * becouse it's always set to null in database by prePersist event callback */

        protected $files_added;

        /**
         * Set container files
         * 
         * @return GalleryAlbum
         */
         public function setFiles($files)
         {
             $this->files = $files;
             $this->files_added = true;
             /* setting files_added to true forces EntityManager to update 
              * this GalleryAlbum even if no other properties have changed */

             return $this;
         }

        /**
         * @ORM\PrePersist()
         * @ORM\PreUpdate()
         */
        public function preUpload()
        {
            if(null !== $this->files) {
                foreach($this->files as $key => $file) {
                  $this->addGalleryElement($file);
                  unset($this->files[$key]);
                }
            }
            /* Resetting property files_added to NULL 
             * so it always stays null in database */
            $this->files_added = null;
        }


        /**
         * Constructing new GalleryImage and setting it's file and parent
         */
        public function addGalleryElement($file)
        {      
            $element = new GalleryImage($this, $file);
            $this->addGalleryImage($element);
        }
    }
```

*# src GalleryImage.php*

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
     * @ORM\Table(name="gallery_image")
     */
    class GalleryImage
    {
        // some properties like id, name, description, etc

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GalleryAlbum", inversedBy="images")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        protected $parent;

        /* Constructing new GalleryImage */ 

        public function __construct($parent = null, $file = null)
        {
            if($parent) $this->setParent($parent);
            if($file) $this->setFile($file);     
        }

        /**
         * @ORM\PrePersist()
         * @ORM\PreUpdate()
         */
        public function preUpload()
        {
            echo 'TEST: is this event callback function fired?'; exit;

            if(null !== $this->file) {
                $this->path = $this->file->guessExtension();
            }

            $this->file_added = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first time you call persist doctrine will only save $album and not its images. You must specify that you want doctrine to cascade the persist by specifying it in the $images declaration:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="GalleryImage", mappedBy="parent", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    protected $images;
```

This way when you call persist($album) it will also persist your images and should trigger preUpload in your GalleryImage. There are a few different options available for cascading and they are explained well here:

[Doctrine transitive persistence cascade operations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations)

Comment: unfortunately adding cascade={"persist", "remove"} or even cascade={"all"} does not change anything :(

Comment: That's strange. I had the same problem a few days ago and this fixed it for me. I'll come back if I think of anything else

Comment: OK i know why double flush works. I am creating new Entities in "prePersist" which means that doctrine ORM already calculated which entities need to be persisted. Thus, when calling flush for the first time - only ALBUM gets persisted. When calling it the 2nd time doctrine sees new entities to be persisted and thats why it saves them to database after 2nd flush.

Comment: I solved my problem by calling "preUpload" in "setFiles" (so, whenever my Album entity gets some files uploaded - it will create entities for them).

Comment: Cool. I'm glad you got to the bottom of it in the end

Comment: finally my stackoverflow score is high enough to accept answers and give +1 :)

Comment: Read the documentation here : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/events.html#preupdate. It says : > Changes to associations of the updated entity are never allowed in this event, since Doctrine cannot guarantee to correctly handle referential integrity at this point of the flush operation.