# why lifecycle methods aren't fired

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have been searching for hours, i really can't understand why ! i have read many SO posts on that ([this for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690903/symfony2-prepersist-preupdate-lifecycle-event-not-fired)), but can't found what the problem is.

I want to [handle File Uploads with Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html), using the `lifecycleCallbacks`, my problem is that the `callbacks` methods never get fired ?

My Entity :

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Etablissement
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="etablissement")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Etablissement
{

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function firstMethod()
{
    exit('inside first method');
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist()
 * @ORM\PostUpdate()
 */
public function secondMethod()
{
    exit('inside secondMethod method');
}
// ...
```

persist code :

```
    $entity = new Etablissement();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();
 // ...........
```

This persists the entity well in database, instead of being `exited` ! please help !

Comment: rebuilded the proxies?

Comment: cache cleared but nothing changes ! @manix what do you mean by "rebuilded proxies"

Comment: everytime you trigger entities property, doctrine at first place create a proxy entity (look your proxies folder) in order to get the attribute value without trying to load the entiry model from the database. So, try to regenerate/rebuild de proxies.

Comment: is this happen on persist or on update, or both?

Comment: i know this has nothing to do with your problem, but maybe you shoud check this bundle. 
https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md
its an easy way to store your uploaded files

Comment: in both persist and update events ! @manix, let me try to do it !

Comment: @manix, how can i regenerate/rebuild proxies, i have read many post about proxies, an i understand why doctrine uses it, but how to do such rebuild ?! help !!!

Comment: Ok, there are some ways to achieve the rebuild. 1. Delete manually all the proxies folder content. Once doctrine detects that there are not proxies, it recreate them from scratch.   2.By console using `orm:generate-proxies`

Comment: Also, if you are not using `namespaces`, try to do the instance like: `$entity = new \Etablissement();`